# Where do I download a version of Lucene.net?

Tags: lucene.net

The link, http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/ contains a download link named Lucene.Net source, but the Lucene directory in the repository only leads back to itself.  Does any one know where I can download the source so I can compile a version 2.4 dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/lucene.net/

And 2.4 is here https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/lucene.net/tags/Lucene.Net_2_4_0/